# How can I generate a function to represent a collection of probabilities so that I can estimate between points

Tags: probability, statistics

Originally posted on Stack overflow but I realize this is more of a statistics problem rather than the software implementation.  Maybe just be aware that I intend to use software to solve my problem so that may present additional solutions.

My particular issue is that I am trying to find a better way to forecast for my business.
I have a table of jobs and their likelihood. that looks like this:

| job | % likely | potential hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Job 1 | .4 | 40 |
| job 2 | .5 | 32 |

and so on for about 25 jobs.

What I want is to generate a curve that shows that out of all the possible jobs, what is the probability of winning a certain number of hours.

We have a high likelihood of winning 10 hours because that requires only a few jobs or just one of the bigger ones and that likely hood decreases as we approach the sum of all hours for jobs being a very low likelihood because it depends on winning all jobs. jobs are not connected in any way, so winning one job does not impact the probability of another.

I have this data brought into a python datafram. I am just unsure on the proper way to combine all of these probabilities so that I can check what is the probability of winning a certain number of hours. I expect that we will be able to calculate some particular points and then fit a curve. If I can get to the point where I can get those points then I can fit the curve.

Chat gpt was not helpful, because it was just trying to multiply all of the probabilities cumulatively, which I believe is not correct. I started to see what it would look like to basically create all possible combinations of: winning 1 job,2 jobs, 3 jobs, 4 jobs, 5 jobs, 6 jobs, and then those probabilities are easy to calculate, then I could fit all those datapoints. But I stopped because I figured there must be a more elegant way and I think this is wrong anyway. if there are two totally exclusive combinations that produce a 20% chance of getting 40 hours then I shouldn't average them because they are probabilities...my Chance of getting 40 hours is better than 20%.

Comment: Seems somewhat related to this:

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1827153/1266819

but the hours aspect is added whereas the linked question is simply winning certain scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done efficiently using recursion.  You can define a function that takes a list of likelihood/hour pairs `(p,h)` for some jobs and returns a `Counter` mapping the total number of hours to the respective probability.

```
from collections import Counter

def dhours(jobs):
    """Calculate distribution of total hours for jobs (p,h) with likelihood
       p and hours h."""
    n = len(p)
```

The base case for zero jobs just returns the distribution where we get zero hours with probability 1:

```
    if n == 0:
        return Counter({0 : 1})
```

For the recursive case, first we calculate the distribution for all but the first job, and then we consider the two cases where we don't get the job (same hours, with each probability multiplied by $1-p$), and add in the additional cases where we get the job (for each possible number of hours for the other jobs, add $h$ hours with probability $p$).  Mathematically this is the convolution of the number of hours from the first job with the total number of hours from the remaining jobs:

```
    else:
        (p,h) = jobs[0]
        # get distribution of n-1 jobs
        dist = dhours(jobs[1:])
        # no job: same hours w/ probability 1-p
        c = Counter({hs: ps*(1-p) for hs, ps in dist.items()})
        # got job: h hours w/ probability p
        for hs, ps in dist.items():
            c[h+hs] += p*ps
        return c
```

This works for your example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(dhours([(.4,40),(.5,32)]))
```

giving the answer:

```
Counter({0: 0.3, 32: 0.3, 40: 0.2, 72: 0.2})
```

(e.g., 0 hours with probability 0.3, 32 hours with probability 0.3, etc.).

It should also run okay on 25 jobs:

```
    ps = (0.3, 1.0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7, 0.1, 0.7, 0.2, 0.2,
          0.8, 0.7, 0.9, 0.7, 0.1, 0.7, 0.2, 0.9, 0.7, 0.7,
          1.0, 0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9)
    hs = (15, 38, 76, 40, 51, 20, 72, 31, 33, 31,
          21, 50, 50, 21, 23, 40, 39, 68, 34, 40,
          55, 19, 28, 54, 25)

    print(dhours(list(zip(ps,hs))))
```

though it generates a lot of output (probabilities for 925 unique numbers of hours, in this example).  Generally speaking, it should have big-O performance $O(h\times n^2)$ where $h$ is the total number of hours for all jobs and $n$ is the number of jobs.

The resulting table will give the probabilities for each possible specific number of hours, but you can sort the list by descending numbers of hours and calculate a cumulative sum to get the probabilities for "at least" each possible number of total hours.

Here's the full program:

```
from collections import Counter

def dhours(jobs):
    """Calculate distribution of total hours for jobs (p,h) with likelihood
       p and hours h."""
    n = len(jobs)
    if n == 0:
        return Counter({0 : 1})
    else:
        (p,h) = jobs[0]
        # get distribution of n-1 jobs
        dist = dhours(jobs[1:])
        # no job: same hours w/ probability 1-p
        c = Counter({hs: ps*(1-p) for hs, ps in dist.items()})
        # got job: h hours w/ probability p
        for hs, ps in dist.items():
            c[h+hs] += p*ps
        return c

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(dhours([(.4,40),(.5,32)]))

    ps = (0.3, 1.0, 0.5, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7, 0.1, 0.7, 0.2, 0.2,
          0.8, 0.7, 0.9, 0.7, 0.1, 0.7, 0.2, 0.9, 0.7, 0.7,
          1.0, 0.8, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9)
    hs = (15, 38, 76, 40, 51, 20, 72, 31, 33, 31,
          21, 50, 50, 21, 23, 40, 39, 68, 34, 40,
          55, 19, 28, 54, 25)

    print(dhours(list(zip(ps,hs))))
```

Comment: Very clever.  I had drafted an answer while you posted yours that was similar but brute forced the combinations rather than using recursion.  So I deleted quickly before anyone saw!!  I might try to rework yours not using the counter and rather adding values to a dataframe.  I will post that if it doesn't blow it up.